# How accurate is the PPS device?

Tags: timestamps, time, synchronization, real-time

I am doing research in timing synchronization, and want to measure how time synchronization is impacted by injecting various faults into a system. I understand that the PPS devices on linux machines have text files like "assert" associated with them that give you a time and sequence ID. How precise/reliable are these timestamps? (source: https://docs.kernel.org/driver-api/pps.html)

For context, the /dev/pps0 in the Linux Kernel is the device I am talking about, it is associated with my Intel I210 NIC. I am synchronizing my Intel I210 NIC to another Intel NIC on another PC, using ptp4l. When I have the synchronization working, I can see that the PPS assertion `cat /sys/class/pps/pps0/assert` gives a timestamp and sequence ID every second, but I'm unsure how reliable this figure is. (Edit: The following link in Table 2 shows that Kernel PPS is accurate to about 1 us ([link](https://gpsd.gitlab.io/gpsd/gpsd-time-service-howto.html))). The same timestamp can be found using the testpps utility ([link](https://github.com/redlab-i/pps-tools)).

The alternative is to probe the physical PPS output on the NIC itself, which presumably is more accurate, but my Intel I210 NIC doesn't seem to have a physical PPS output that I can probe with an oscilloscope.

**Edit 2:** To alleviate some confusions, I will provide an image that shows how I can probe the 1PPS signal of both PCs to compare the reference clock signal (from the Grandmaster), and compare against the slave clock, using an oscilloscope:

[image: Physically probing 1PPS signals using Oscilloscope]

The alternative would be to keep track of the `assert` timestamp (assuming it does what I think it does) and use that to compare when the 1PPS signal for the GM and slave are asserted, and compare the two to assess synchronization. My question was, how accurate is this `assert` timestamp? @Bib has noted that they achieve 500 ns jitter, and I've seen online that its accuracy can be around 1 us. Because I'd prefer to get the most accurate indication of how accurately the devices within the GM and slave clocks are synced, it makes most sense to go with the Oscilloscope solution, assuming the Intel I210 NIC has a physical 1PPS output that can be probed.

Comment: Which devices are you specifically referring to?

Comment: And what exactly are you synchronizing?

Comment: PPS on the NIC? Don't you mean PTP on the NIC? How accurate the PPS is, depends on whether you have kernel PPS support enabled or not (it usually is not). If it is, then you would get down to around ~500ns jitter, but could go to ~10ns. That is what I see on my RPi.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have edited my post to enhance clarity and address your questions.

Comment: @Bib Yes, PTP is running on my machine, but I am needing to assess synchronization accuracy with as high of precision + accuracy as possible. I believe Kernel PPS is enabled, because I am able to view ```cat /sys/class/pps/pps0/assert``` which gives me a timestamp every second. Your answer does address my question though, thanks. I was hoping that if the NIC had a 1PPS signal, that it would be able to be probed using an oscilloscope or digital analyzer, instead of using Kernel PPS. I would assume probing the physical signal to be more accurate.

Comment: Not sure if `assert` file is an indicator, all distros seem not have it enabled as there is a hz conflict. Look at the `dmesg` output. You will be looking for 2 lines similar to `pps pps0: Registered IRQ 67 as PPS source` & `pps pps0: bound kernel consumer: edge=0x1`. It's the second one which is important.

Comment: You may also find it easier to run `ppstest /dev/pps0`. That however is no indicator as to whether it is being consumed by the kernel.

Comment: @stochasticlover1 I'm very confused now. Against *what* do you want to assess the quality of your PPS? This is analogous of standing in a forest with a ruler and proclaiming you want to assess the accuracy of your ruler; that 1 cm on it really 1 cm. That's fine, but you'll need another ruler, a known-to-be-much better one than yours, or very many statistically independent rulers, to compare your ruler against. You can't ask the device itself "are you accurate?". How should it know?

Comment: @stochasticlover1 Even "hardware PPS signal verification against an oscilloscope": I mean, syncE + PTP conmpensate for the speed of light in your links. I don't see how your proposed oscilloscope solution does that compensation? Or did you plan to deembed and incorporate the delay/length of your scope's probes into your calculation?

Comment: @stochasticlover1 what's even more confusing is that you say you synchronize two Ethernet interfaces *using software*? How is that supposed to work? The interrupt latencies in your computer are orders of magnitude slower than the synchronization that SyncE + PTP do. Something's really strange with my understanding of your setup! Please alleviate my confusion :)!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have edited my post to make it more clear how my setup looks (incl a diagram). It's a very simple GM with an Intel I210 NIC, connected via Ethernet to a slave with another NIC that has a 1PPS output. Yes, ptp4l is a daemon within the linuxptp instance that allows you to synchronize two clocks across an ethernet link. Take a look: https://linuxptp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Bib I'll take a look at the ```dmesg``` output tomorrow, but my understanding of the ```assert``` is that it does not need to be consumed by the kernel. My understanding (based off https://docs.kernel.org/driver-api/pps.html under "SYSFS support" and "Testing the PPS support") is that ```assert``` is a timestamp that is asserted every second according to the NIC, which can at least allow you to assess syntonization between two devices if collected on both the GM and slave devices (view the updated post for a diagram of a sample setup)

Comment: @Bib I've also tried ```ppstest /dev/pps0``` and I am getting an output as expected, but my question was more: how accurate is this timestamp? I think I've gotten the answer, according to you, it's around 500 ns of jitter, and according to another source I've seen 1 us. Because of this, I've decided to physically probe the 1PPS output on the NIC instead of using Kernel PPS to assess the quality of synchronization. It's just not always possible to physically probe signals, if the two devices are far away from each other, like they would be if we were synchronizing across a wireless link.

Comment: Like I said, higher accuracy requires the kernel consumer which is NOT enabled by default. It will also depend on the timer tick handling, preemption model & timer frequency. It will also depend on what else the kernel is heavily i/o bound. If the kernel is busy doing other things, then it will not accept the pps until it is ready to do so and to give it a timestamp.